# Highlight points in ArrayPlot in the same way that it happens to DensityHistrogram

Tags: plotting, interactive

I was wondering if there is any way to highlight the values in ArrayPlot in the same way that it is possible for DensityHistogram. Something along the lines of the plot below but in cases where I already have the array.

```
data = RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {100, 2}];
DensityHistogram[data, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
m = Partition[Range @ 20, 5];

ArrayPlot[m, Mesh -> All, 
 Epilog -> MapIndexed[Tooltip[{Opacity[0], Rectangle[#2 - 1]}, Style[#, 16]]&,
   Transpose @ Reverse @ m, {2}]]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! while this work it is actually not aligned well:
```
ArrayPlot[m, Mesh -> All, 
 Epilog -> 
  MapIndexed[
   Tooltip[{Opacity[.5], Rectangle[#2 - 1/2]}, Style[#, 16]] &, 
   Transpose@Reverse@m, {2}]]
``` reveals this.

Comment: Thank you @elbOlita; fixed the alignment issue.